# How do I get sub/super scripts to render automatically?

Tags: latex, elisp, org-mode

I'm curious as to how I could get org-mode to automatically render sub/superscripts. [Here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Subscripts-and-superscripts.html) is the org-mode wiki page on using this. At the moment I can properly get it to work but I need to use "C-c C-x \". Is there some code solution I could put in my init.el file or something to get this to execute when opening any file?

Comment: What happens if you customize org-pretty-entities and org-pretty-entities-include-sub-superscripts?

Comment: I just toggled org-pretty-entities and that did the trick. Thanks. If you want to make an answer I will accept that or I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I toggled org-pretty-entities with **M-x**, `org-toggle-pretty-entities` and that did the trick. Alternatively you could place `#+STARTUP entitiespretty` at the beginning of your file.